# TypeScript trying to use adaljs

Tags: angular, adal.js

I am developing an application using Angular2 with TypeScript.  Part of that requires the use of ADALJS.  As I understand I cannot use the angular part in this library since it only supports Angular1, so I plan to use just adal.js.  My question around this is

1. I installed definitelytyped from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/24295668a2e66f9daed4e383e22074d8452505a1/adal-angular (adal.d.ts)
2. Into my login component I added
   `///</// <reference path="adal.d.ts" />`
3. Onto the top of the class (component) I added

   import * as adal from "adal-angular/dist/adal.min";

However when I run the application I get an error

**angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/adal-angular/dist/adal.min.js(…)**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try using adal-ts

```
npm install adal-ts --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the reference to the type definitions (adal.d.ts) is not the same as adding a reference to adal.js itself.

To reference the file from a CDN, add to your html:

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.11/js/adal.min.js"></script>
```

Or, you could install adal-angular package from NPM:

```
npm install adal-angular
```

See https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js for more information.